# Learning Haskell: where-clause variable x, where does it come from?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and this will be my first post.

In the great online book http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where there is the example `largestDivisble`. In the where-clause the variable `x` is introduced but where does it come from? Untill now the variables where bounded in the pattern-matching part of the function body.

As I now interpret it: 
the part `where p x` declares the function `p` and the application of some variable `x`. In the body `filter p [some-list]`, the some-list stands for `x`.

I think this is all a bit fuzzy. Can someone help me out with a explanation of this piece of code?

```
    largestDivisible :: (Integral a) => a  
    largestDivisible = head (filter p [100000,99999..])  
        where p x = x `mod` 3829 == 0
```

Comment: Yuck, what an implementation. ```largestDivisible = 100000 - 100000 `mod` 3829``` seems much more direct.

Comment: Yes, that is the smart way, But of course, this is an example to demonstrate the filter function :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x` there is just the function argument. It's entirely local to the definition of `p`.

You could have defined it as a separate, top-level function, like this:

```
p :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
p x = x `mod` 3829 == 0
```

and note that the type signature here isn't required, it's just good practice to include it for a top level function. The definition of `p` in the `where` clause is identical, including `x` being a local name for the function argument. The only difference between the two is that a function defined in a `where` clause is local to the definition that includes that clause, and can't be accessed outside.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer confirmed my sumption.  The statement " It's entirely local to the definition of p" does make it all clear now. So the where clause just defined a new function but local to the enclosing function. :)

Comment: @rik_mg Yes, it is equivalent to `where p = (\x -> x `mod` 3829 == 0)` where on the right hand side we find a lambda/anonymous function `\x -> ...`